# QGIS, deleting last placed vertice while digitizing, can I custom keyboard shortcut this task?

Tags: qgis, vertices, delete, shortcuts

Upon searching this topic, I found the answer of using the delete or backspace key to delete the last placed vertex while editing.

My question, Is it possible to reprogram this delete function to a different keyboard shortcut within qgis?

I would want an alternative, say ctrl+Z or a programmable mouse button for example, something more easily utilized.

Comment: There is a program called "autohotkey" which makes you remap every keyboard-/mouse-shortcut for any program. I do not have a lot of experience with this program but from what I have seen it's pretty simple. Maybe that's an option. I have also looked in QGIS itself, but I don't think it's possible without diving deep into the code.